# Many Bool columns in database table

Tags: mysql, performance, boolean

I recently took over a website where people can register to help tutor kids. Part of the user's details is which areas they could work, represented by postal codes. The problem is, my predecessor designed the site such that in the database there is a Boolean column for every postal code. As such, the user table has almost 270 columns and can be quite slow at times (plus it's a nightmare to administer).

Most users select only a few postal codes so there is surely a better way to do it. I was thinking about a varchar that could save the selected areas comma separated, e.g. `6043,8811,1234`

Any advice from somebody who's had the same problem?

Comment: Comma separated lists in a field are nearly always a bad idea. Consider using another table with a single row for every combination of user, postal code and ability to work. That's common for such issues.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, looks like this company might have to close it's doors so I haven't been around much. I considered a user table & a "postal code for user" table but thought the string would be simpler, it's only about 100 users. I'll take everybody's advice. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both your predecessor's and your solution are... strange.

You should simply have a relationship table between user and localities (assuming you have a locality table, with a postalCode field and a surrogate key (id)).

```
UserLocality(userId int, localityId int)
```

so a locality could have many user, and a user could have many localities.

Coma separated fields is a really bad idea, when query time comes.

Answer (score 0):

You should throw that entire idea out of your head and look into properly normalized data.

A possible solution to this problem would be a table for tutors, which has an id column to uniquely identify one tutor.

Then you would have a table for just Postal Codes (each with unique ids as well) and finally a tutor_availability table that creates one record of (t_id, pc_id) for each postal code a tutor wishes to offer their services, again with a unique id to avoid duplication risks in the case they can select the same location twice.

Comment: Minus 1 - This is almost a repeat of Raphael's answer which was submitted 4 minutes earlier.  The only thing you added was the bad idea of adding a third column to your many to many table.

Comment: I wrote mine before the notification to show his appeared. Calm down.